# Is there a way to un-concatenate in C?

Tags: c

Say if I concatenate one string to another, check if it has passed the line length limit, and if it has passed that limit is there a way to un-concatenate it?

Comment: Why not just check string lengths beforehand?

Comment: I want to add it to what I already have and see if everything as a whole has passed the limit.

Comment: What does "un-concatenate" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you concatenate a string and it passes the length limit, it is usually too late to undo it: assuming that the limit is based on the size of allocated memory, concatenation causes *undefined behavior*. At this point it's all over: your program may crash or do other unexpected things.

That is why you need to check the limit *before* performing concatenation, and if the new length is over the limit, do not perform concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Stored the concatenated string separately and check for its length. If it has passed the limit then use the parent strings that you used for concatenation.